# Freebase: Instances missing in dump

Tags: rdf, freebase

I want to extract all companies from the [Freebase dump](https://developers.google.com/freebase/). However multiple instances appear to be missing in the dump.

For example Volkswagen (`/m/07ywl`) seems to be not included. I searched for the MID using the following regex but could not find any results:

```
zgrep 'rdf\.freebase\.com/ns/m\.07ywl>' freebase-rdf.gz > res.rdf
```

The MID should be valid since it is stated on the corresponding [Wikidata page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q246) and is the top result for Volkswagen when searching for it using the Knowledge Graph API:

```
https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=volkswagen&key=<API-KEY>&limit=5&indent=True
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 because zgrep was interpreting the decompressed data as binary and not decoding the text properly when searching.  Using the `-a` flag fixed the problem for me:

`zgrep -a 'rdf\.freebase\.com/ns/m\.07ywl>' freebase-rdf.gz`

Answer (score 0):

That entity exists in `freebase-rdf-2015-04-19-00-00.gz`, so I'd be pretty surprised if it didn't exist in the final dump from a few months later (2015-08-09) since the database was write-locked for all except a few Google admins.

My first guess would be that you have a truncated or corrupted download. Did you check the length and MD5 checksum after download?

Comment: Sorry for the late followup. Can you show me how you searched for the entity? I tried `zgrep '07ywl'` on the `freebase-rdf-2015-04-19-00-00.gz` dump and did not retrieve any results.

Comment: `$ time zgrep '07ywl' freebase-rdf-2015-04-19-00-00.gz > vw-07ywl.txt  
    real 86m51.942s  
    user 84m33.558s  
    sys 0m39.977s  
    $ wc -l vw-0*  
    1344 vw-07ywl.txt`  
Did you check the length and checksum after downloading?

Comment: They don't publish checksums. However the size of the archive looks good and I tested that the compression is not corrupt using `gunzip -t`.

Comment: Not sure how else to check things. Despite the crappy the formatting, the gist of it is that my copy of that file has 1334 triples that match that pattern. This is on OS X, but I'd be surprised if `zgrep` behaved differently on other platforms.